# How can i set the id of the selected object in the dropdown list below

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am using this flutter dropdown_search package [package link here](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search). For now i can be able to get the items from the api and display them respectively. The only challenge i am having right now is to get the id of the selected item on change so i can submit the form. if i change the dropdown type to the object i am using it complains so I don't know what to do please i need help.

Image of the Ui
[image]

Widget code:

```
      Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: DropdownSearch<dynamic>(
            mode: Mode.MENU,
            items: controller.listAccountTypeModel_.value.map((e) => e.name).toList(),
            showSearchBox: true,
             dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Account Types",
              hintText: "Different Account Types",
            ),
            onChanged: ( value) {
              print('dropdown value');
              controller.setAccountTypeId(value);
            },
            selectedItem: "Savings",
          ),
        ),
```

Controller:

```
 void getMaritalStatus(String url) {
print("get MaritalStatus");
try {
  Get.dialog(Center(
    child: SpinKitDualRing(
      color: Colors.green,
      lineWidth: 2,
    ),
  ));

  repository.getLoadedMaritalStatusData(url).then((value) {
    if (value.maritalStatusValues!.length > 0) {
      print("get MaritalStatus data: ${value.toString()}");
      Get.back();
      listMaritalStatusModel_.value.clear();
      listMaritalStatusModel_.value.addAll(value.maritalStatusValues!);
      refresh();
      listMaritalStatusDropDownMenuItem.value = [];
      listMaritalStatusDropDownMenuItem.value.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(
            'Select MaritalStatus',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          value: "0",
        ),
      );
      for (MaritalStatusValues maritalStatus
          in listMaritalStatusModel_.value) {
        print(maritalStatus.toJson());

        listMaritalStatusDropDownMenuItem.value.add(
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(
              maritalStatus.description.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            value: maritalStatus.id.toString(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
    print(error.toString());
    Get.back();
    //error handling code
  });
} catch (exception) {
  print(exception.toString());
  Get.back();
  // exception handling code
}
```

}

```
  String? validateAccountType(String value) {
    if (value == "0") {
      return "Select AccountType";
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Package version in the pubspec.yaml

**dropdown_search: ^3.0.1**

AccoutType Model Class

```
class AccountType {
  int? statusCode;
  int? count;
  String? message;
  List<AccountTypeValues>? accountTypeValues;

  AccountType({this.statusCode, this.count, this.message, this.accountTypeValues});

  AccountType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    statusCode = json['statusCode'];
    count = json['count'];
    message = json['message'];
    if (json['values'] != null) {
      accountTypeValues = <AccountTypeValues>[];
      json['values'].forEach((v) {
        accountTypeValues!.add(new AccountTypeValues.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['statusCode'] = this.statusCode;
    data['count'] = this.count;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    if (this.accountTypeValues != null) {
      data['values'] = this.accountTypeValues!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class AccountTypeValues {
  int? oid;
  String? name;
  String? createdBy;
  String? createdOn;
  String? modifiedBy;
  String? modifiedOn;
  Null? pcDomainName;
  Null? pcIpAddress;
  Null? pcName;
  Null? pcUserName;

  AccountTypeValues(
      {this.oid,
      this.name,
      this.createdBy,
      this.createdOn,
      this.modifiedBy,
      this.modifiedOn,
      this.pcDomainName,
      this.pcIpAddress,
      this.pcName,
      this.pcUserName});

  AccountTypeValues.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    oid = json['oid'];
    name = json['name'];
    createdBy = json['createdBy'];
    createdOn = json['createdOn'];
    modifiedBy = json['modifiedBy'];
    modifiedOn = json['modifiedOn'];
    pcDomainName = json['pcDomainName'];
    pcIpAddress = json['pcIpAddress'];
    pcName = json['pcName'];
    pcUserName = json['pcUserName'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['oid'] = this.oid;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['createdBy'] = this.createdBy;
    data['createdOn'] = this.createdOn;
    data['modifiedBy'] = this.modifiedBy;
    data['modifiedOn'] = this.modifiedOn;
    data['pcDomainName'] = this.pcDomainName;
    data['pcIpAddress'] = this.pcIpAddress;
    data['pcName'] = this.pcName;
    data['pcUserName'] = this.pcUserName;
    return data;
  }
}
```

HTTP service class

```
 Future<AccountType> getAccountTypeData(String url) async {
    try {
      final response = await get(BaseEndpoint.baseUrl + url );
      if (response.status.hasError) {
        return Future.error(response.statusText!);
      } else {
        return AccountType.fromJson(response.body) ;
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      return Future.error(exception.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you select something, you can't see it? your data can't be changed?

Comment: i get this **type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'AccountTypeValues?'**

Comment: when you tap on your DropDown options?

Comment: try to use listMaritalStatusDropDownMenuItem.value.valueOf(object) to get the index of an object from this list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't get the id is you did not specify `id` property in your model class. when creating a model class, it should always have unique identification that you'll use to get the document by id. because if you let the database to generate the id for you, there is no way you can retrieve it from the client side because you don't have control over it. So to make it work add an `id` property on your model class so that you can query it from your app.

Comment: ok this is the class i am focused on in the model class sir **AccountTypeValues** it is a nested class in the main class